# How can I calculate how many nights are there in a date range?

Tags: c#, date

I need to calculate the quantity of nights (stay at a hotel) from the checkin and checkout dates.

What is the best way to do it?

ie: If I have

```
Checkin:  12/11/2009 15:00 hs  
Checkout:  14/11/2009 12:00 hs
```

Doing `(Checkout - Checkin).Days` would give me 1 night instead of 2

I'm thinking of adding a simple `if` to check the hours (if checkin-time is greater than checkout-time) and add the missing night, but maybe there's a better "algorithm"

Comment: Are you accounting for late arrivals, too?  What if a person check's in after midnight?  A late arrival that has a one day stay would still be leaving the same morning, but technically still stayed a "night".

Comment: It doesn't matter when he arrived, it's for the confirmation mail when he makes the reservation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

DateTime has a property that returns the Date part which is the DateTime in midnight. You can use this part to get the nights since all parts of day will be mapped to the same time at day:

```
(Checkout.Date - Checkin.Date).Days
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I need more coffee =)